# assigning values to string array android

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays

I made a string array in xml and I would like to add values to each one. As they are currencies, each would have its own value but i'm unsure as to how to do it.

```
<string-array name="currencies">
    <item>EUR, Euro</item>
    <item>GBP, British Pound</item>
    <item>USD, US Dollar</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: How is this xml stored? Start there.

Comment: This is a valid `string-array`. What problem are you facing?

Comment: the xml is stored in res/values/strings.xml

Comment: @vikram the problem im facing is that i call the array in spinners in the java class. I want that when i select for example GBP that value 1.56 is selected also, as that is the value that is assigned to GBP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use this for preferences you should try this:

```
<string-array name="currencies">
    <item>EUR, Euro</item>
    <item>GBP, British Pound</item>
    <item>USD, US Dollar</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="currenciesvalues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

So the value of Euro is 1, the value of British Pound is 2, and so on. Like I said, if you use this in a preferenceactivity or preferencefragment, you can set the items, and the corresponding values like this:

```
android:entries="@array/currencies"
android:entryValues="@array/currenciesvalues"
```